# Sorting class based on attributes 'object is not subscriptable'

Tags: python, class, sorting, lambda

I have almost finished my project for creating a scoreboard based on user input. However, when it comes to my last step, sorting based on the results given, my code does not seem to function. The output that I receive is as follows:

```
["player_result(name='Trees', points=0.5, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.5, black=1)", "player_result(name='Erik', points=1.0, resistance_points=1.5, sonnenborn_berger=0.75, black=1)", "player_result(name='Udo', points=1.0, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Ronald', points=1.0, resistance_points=2.5, sonnenborn_berger=1.25, black=1)", "player_result(name='Truus', points=1.0, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Omar', points=0.0, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Cornelis', points=1.0, resistance_points=1.5, sonnenborn_berger=0.0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Ria', points=1.5, resistance_points=2.5, sonnenborn_berger=1.75, black=1)", "player_result(name='Otto', points=1.0, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Emma', points=1.0, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Henk', points=1.5, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.5, black=1)", "player_result(name='Ulrich', points=1.0, resistance_points=2.0, sonnenborn_berger=0.5, black=1)", "player_result(name='Cor', points=1.5, resistance_points=2.5, sonnenborn_berger=1.75, black=1)", "player_result(name='Piet', points=1.0, resistance_points=1.5, sonnenborn_berger=0.0, black=1)", "player_result(name='Theo', points=2.0, resistance_points=1.0, sonnenborn_berger=1.0, black=0)", "player_result(name='Thea', points=0.0, resistance_points=3.0, sonnenborn_berger=0, black=2)"]
```

What I would like to see is that these items are sorted from highest to lowest in the following order: points, resistance-points, sonnenborn-berger, black.

I have looked into the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) documentation, on which I based the 2 sorted() lines in my code.
However, the sorted(print_list) line gives no errors, but does not sort, and the sorted(return_list) line gives the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "{file}", line 70, in <module>
    determine_output("""Trees
  File "{file}", line 65, in determine_output
    sorted_return_list = sorted(return_list, key=itemgetter(1, 2, 3, 4), reverse=True)
TypeError: 'player_result' object is not subscriptable
```

My question: how can I sort my class objects based on the attributes mentioned above? I am more 'concerned' that the return value is sorted as expected; the print value is to make the sorting 'visible to me'. For full clarity, my code is as follows:

```
from operator import itemgetter


class player_result:
    def __init__(self, name: str, points: float, resistance_points: float, sonnenborn_berger: float, black: int):
        self.name = name
        self.points = points
        self.resistance_points = resistance_points
        self.sonnenborn_berger = sonnenborn_berger
        self.black = black

    def __str__(self):
        return 'player_result(name=\'' + self.name + '\', points=' + str(self.points) + ', resistance_points=' + \
               str(self.resistance_points) + ', sonnenborn_berger=' + str(self.sonnenborn_berger) + \
               ', black=' + str(self.black) + ')'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name and self.points == other.points and \
               self.resistance_points == other.resistance_points and \
               self.sonnenborn_berger == other.sonnenborn_berger and self.black == other.black


def determine_output(input: str):
    # splitten van lijnen
    splits = input.split("\n\n")
    rounds = [i.split('\n') for i in splits]
    # bepalen van players
    players = {}
    for name in rounds[0]:
        players[name] = player_result(name, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    # bepalen van points van iedere player
    for one_round in rounds[1:]:
        for game in one_round:
            white_player, black_player, result_white_player, result_black_player = game.split()
            players[white_player].points += float(result_white_player)
            players[black_player].points += float(result_black_player)
            players[black_player].black += 1
    # bepalen van resistance_points van iedere player
    # Uitleg: totaalscore van alle tegenstanders per speler toevoegen aan player
    for one_round in rounds[1:]:
        for game in one_round:
            white_player, black_player, result_white_player, result_black_player = game.split()
            players[white_player].resistance_points += players[black_player].points
            players[black_player].resistance_points += players[white_player].points
    # bepalen van sonneborn_berger van iedere player
    # Uitleg: 1 * punten van verliezers + 0,5 * punten van gelijk toevoegen aan player
    for one_round in rounds[1:]:
        for game in one_round:
            white_player, black_player, result_white_player, result_black_player = game.split()
            if float(result_white_player) == 1:
                players[white_player].sonnenborn_berger += 1 * players[black_player].points
            if float(result_white_player) == 0.5:
                players[white_player].sonnenborn_berger += 0.5 * players[black_player].points
            if float(result_black_player) == 1:
                players[black_player].sonnenborn_berger += 1 * players[white_player].points
            if float(result_black_player) == 0.5:
                players[black_player].sonnenborn_berger += 0.5 * players[white_player].points
    # sorteren: points > resistance_points > sonneborn_berger > black (van hoog naar laag)
    print_list = []
    return_list = []
    for player in players.values():
        print_list.append(str(player))
        return_list.append(player)
    print_list = sorted(print_list, key=itemgetter(1, 2, 3, 4), reverse=True)
    return_list = sorted(return_list, key=itemgetter(1, 2, 3, 4), reverse=True)
    print(print_list)
    return return_list


determine_output("""Trees
Erik
Udo
Ronald
Truus
Omar
Cornelis
Ria
Otto
Emma
Henk
Ulrich
Cor
Piet
Theo
Thea

Trees Erik 0.5 0.5
Udo Ronald 0.5 0.5
Truus Omar 1 0
Cornelis Ria 0 1
Otto Emma 0.5 0.5
Henk Ulrich 1 0
Cor Piet 1 0
Theo Thea 1 0

Ria Cor 0.5 0.5
Theo Truus 1 0
Ronald Henk 0.5 0.5
Emma Udo 0.5 0.5
Erik Otto 0.5 0.5
Ulrich Trees 1 0
Piet Thea 1 0
Omar Cornelis 0 1""")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

To resolve the error, you can use [`attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) instead of `itemgetter()`. It works similarly, but is used to get attributes, not items.

You seem to confuse the two. Attributes are usually belong to objects, and are accessed by the dot-syntax: `result.name`. Items are usually belong to sequences (lists, tuples, etc.) and are accessed via the `my_list[item_index]` syntax. Objects of your class have attributes, not items.

The other problem is the sorting of the print and returns lists. The `print_list` sorting does not error out, even tho you used the same method for sorting them, but also won't get sorted correctly. The issue is, that the list does not contain `player_result` instances, but strings. This also means the `itemgetter` works on them, as they are sequences - but result in some strange alphabetic ordering instead of the intended. To fix it, you should sort the list before converting to `str` (and like that, you only need to sort the data once).

Comment: Using attrgetter() has solved the problem, now it sorts correctly when returning. Thanks so much!

Used code:
`return_list = sorted(return_list, key=attrgetter('points', 'resistance_points', 'sonnenborn_berger', 'black'), reverse=True)`

Comment: @AndrewRed Be sure to fix the sorting of `print_list` too!